# Spaces appear after file_get_contents from HTML file

Tags: javascript, php

I have 2 files: script.html and index.php.

*My purpose* is to generate a text (in this case the country of the user) in an HTML file by a JavaScript. This is the code of this HTML file:

> *script.html*

```
<script language="Javascript" src="http://www.codehelper.io/api/ips/?js"></script>
<script language="Javascript">document.write(codehelper_ip.Country);</script>
```

And now, *I want to* take that text to the PHP file to use it as a variable:

> *index.php*

```
<?php
$content = file_get_contents(script.html);
echo "http://www.example.com/$content/example"
?>
```

*The problem* is that the output from that *echo* is odd:

> echo output:

```
http://www.example.com/ US /example
```

Notice **the spaces before and after the "US"**. This destroys the whole purpose of the code, of course. I can't have that URL like that.

Any way I can **avoid or remove those spaces?**

Why is this happening?

*My guess*: These spaces are being inserted because of the linebreaks of the JavaScript code. If I don't put any linebreak between one `<script></script>` and the other `<script></script>` (such as `<script language="Javascript" src="http://www.codehelper.io/api/ips/?js"></script><script language="Javascript">document.write(codehelper_ip.Country);</script>`, all in one line) then I get `http://www.example.com/US /example`. I don't know how I could avoid the space after, though.

*Note1:* I have already tried **trim()** (I use PHP 5+ so it should work). I also tried changing the file extension ".html" to ".php" just in case it would do something, but it doesn't.

*Note2:* Even though I know I could do it some other way, I want to get the country of the user through JavaScript and not through PHP. The reason is that I can't do it via server using my current hosting plan, so I thought of JavaScript instead.

Thank you very much.

Comment: This makes no sense at all. file_get_contents will not execute your JS code. Look at the output of your script in the _source_ code (or wrap it into `htmlspecialchars()`), then you will see what your script actually does.

Comment: I knew that file_get_contents would not execute the JS code. What I didn't take into consideration was what @Boann said in his answer. But I see now, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're muddled about when the various scripts are executed.

```
$content = file_get_contents(script.html);
```

At this point, `$content` contains the `<script>` tags. The JavaScript has not been executed as the JavaScript has not yet been sent to the browser.

```
echo "http://www.example.com/$content/example"
```

That sends this to the browser:

```
http://www.example.com/<script language="Javascript" src="http://www.codehelper.io/api/ips/?js"></script>
<script language="Javascript">document.write(codehelper_ip.Country);</script>/example
```

Since the PHP is so trivial, try this plain JavaScript solution instead:

```
<script language="Javascript" src="http://www.codehelper.io/api/ips/?js"></script>
<script language="Javascript">document.write("http://www.example.com/" + codehelper_ip.Country + "/example");</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution, I am using it.